# How to deal with big numeric values from response in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have to read a JSON response which contains the value which is greater than  MAX_SAFE_INTEGER without loss of precision. Like I had values

```
 value1 =  232333433534534634534411
```

And I have to process that value and convert to

```
 value2 =  +232333433534534634534411.0000
```

without any loss of precision?

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov BigInt doesn't work for me and while I am using toString() to convert the number into string it loses precision.

Comment: what do you do after converting with the number?

Comment: @ninaScholz I had to compare it with the saved response.

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov No, I don't have backend controls

Comment: do you have an example of comparing and what is the expected result?

Comment: @NinaScholz I have to convert the upper value into the lower format and compare them they are equal or not?

Comment: what is an upper value? please add some data.

Comment: @NinaScholz I made an Edit upper value means value1 and lower value means value2

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220975/discussion-between-ninja-and-nina-scholz).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can't be done with standard `JSON.parse`:

```js
JSON.parse('{"prop": 232333433534534634534411}')
// {prop: 2.3233343353453462e+23}
```

### If you have control over the API producing the JSON

You can use a string instead, then create a `BigInt` out of it (assuming legacy browser support isn't required).

```js
const result = JSON.parse('{"prop": "232333433534534634534411"}')
const int = BigInt(result.prop)
// 232333433534534634534411n
```

If you need to perform decimal arithmetic on this result with a precision of 4 decimal places, you can multiply it by `10000n`, for example:

```js
const tenThousandths = int * 10000n // 2323334335345346345344110000n
const sum = tenThousandths + 55000n + 21n * 2n // 2323334335345346345344165042n
const fractionalPart = sum % 10000n // 5042n
const wholePart = sum / 10000n // 232333433534534634534416n (floor division)
const reStringified = `${wholePart}.${fractionalPart}` // "232333433534534634534416.5042"

const newJson = JSON.stringify({prop: reStringified})
// '{"prop":"232333433534534634534416.5042"}'
```

For legacy browser support, you could do similar with a library such as [BigInteger.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/big-integer).

### If you don't control the API

In this case, you'll need a custom JSON parsing library, such as [lossless JSON](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lossless-json).

Comment: I appreciate this and it completely justified but I don't have control over API and I have to treat it as a number only as if I convert it to a string using toString() it just loses precision .

Comment: @Ninja A JSON parsing library is the only sensible way to go then. You could try some hacky solution by grepping for the property name (assuming there aren't multiple of the same property name on different elements), but that type of approach will always be brittle.

Answer (score 1):

You could split by dot and treat the digits after the dot.

```js
const convert = string => {
    const values = string.split('.');
    values[1] = (values[1] || '').padEnd(4, 0).slice(0, 4);    
    return values.join('.');
};

console.log(convert('232333433534534634534411'));
console.log(convert('232333433534534634534411.12345'));
```

Comment: I appreciate your effort but the problem with this is when I change it to string it already loses its precision

Comment: why? just take the `JSON` without conversion.

Comment: in JSON it should be a string. otherwise it's just a number and no [JSON](https://json.org/).

Comment: In the JSON I am using  it was like   "MarketValue":534534534545335

Comment: then take the number from the string by looking for `"MarketValue":`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220976/discussion-between-nina-scholz-and-ninja).